# Anaconda python environment disappeared from VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Used to be able to use anaconda python in VS code (ubuntu 20.04). Now the VS code option for Conda environments disappeared and I'm not sure why. Reloading the VS code/rebooting the computer sometimes gives me back the conda environment. But it will disappear again when I open another .ipynb file.

This happened after me opening a jupyter notebook file on a mounted SFTP server, direclty from the files app. That notebook worked fine actually. After closing that notebook, I cannot see my conda environment in other notebooks.

I tried loading the python enviroments by pressing "Ctrl + Shift + P". There I can see all python environments and can select anyone I like. I can also run ".py" scripts without a problem. But in Jupyter notebook I cannot select the Conda environments.

Comment: Have you tried to perform a clean reinstall? It might be due to extension conflicts

Comment: Thanks for your comment! How do I perform a clean reinstall? If I simply uninstall/reinstall it seems to remember all extension settings.

Comment: Follow the steps in this question: [How to COMPLETELY uninstall Visual Studio Code from Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1380208/1740778)

Comment: Install jupyter for the current environment using `python -m pip install jupyter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the comments! Since I want to use the anaconda environment, not my current environment, a clean uninstall/reinstall worked for me in the end. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and followed the instructions on this Visual Studio Code [webpage](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall). Not sure what caused the problem in the beginning, might be some extension packages related to SSH.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).